# r - Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports): undefined exports: dim_na<-,

Tags: r, namespaces, r-caret

I'm getting the following error with the command `library(caret)` in R:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports): undefined exports: dim_na<-, as.listenv, get_variable, listenv, map, mapping, parse_env_subset, undim

I'm also getting the following warning:

> In addition: Warning message:
> S3 methods ‘$.listenv’, ‘$<-.listenv’, ‘[.listenv’, ‘[<-.listenv’, ‘[[.listenv’, ‘[[<-.listenv’, ‘dim<-.listenv’, ‘dimnames<-.listenv’, ‘length<-.listenv’, ‘names<-.listenv’, ‘all.equal.listenv’, ‘as.list.listenv’, ‘as.listenv.default’, ‘as.listenv.environment’, ‘as.listenv.list’, ‘as.listenv.listenv’, ‘as.matrix.listenv’, ‘as.vector.listenv’, ‘dim.listenv’, ‘dimnames.listenv’, ‘get_variable.listenv’, ‘is.array.listenv’, ‘is.matrix.listenv’, ‘length.listenv’, ‘lengths.listenv’, ‘names.listenv’, ‘print.listenv’, ‘undim.default’, ‘undim.listenv’, ‘unlist.listenv’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found

I've tried removing and reinstalling caret but that did nothing. Any pointers even (like what are the listenv methods) would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: may be try installing the dependencies.

Comment: So 'install.packages("caret", dependencies = TRUE)'?

Comment: Ah, that helps. Thanks. I tried it and got a different error saying 'there is no package called ‘listenv’'. So I did some more digging and it looks like I have a permissions problem (error 0x80004005) on my listenv directory. So I'll have to ask IT to take care of it since it's a company computer. Thank you!